# Webscraping using httr:GET function gives 'status: 503'

Tags: r, get, httr

I'm trying to connect to a website using the GET function from the httr package on a work pc.

When I try

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://httpbin.org/get"
GET(url)
```

I get Status: 503. When I use the RCurl library to check whether the link exists

```
library(RCurl)
url.exists(url)
```

It says FALSE, although the link does exist.

Finally, using the following does work:

```
readLines(url)
```

Anyone an idea how to get the GET function working?

************* Update ******************
When I run

```
library(httr)
with_verbose(GET("http://httpbin.org/get"))
```

I get the following output:

```
library(httr)
Warning message:
package ‘httr’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
with_verbose(GET("http://httpbin.org/get"))
GET /get HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
User-Agent: libcurl/7.47.1 r-curl/0.9.7 httr/1.1.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3
Connection: close
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache

Response [http://httpbin.org/get]
Date: 2017-02-02 15:08
Status: 503
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Size: 3 B
```

Comment: The problem was a gnarly proxy server. Added `http_proxy=http://username:pwd@proxyname:port` to the .Renviron file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you are in an environment in which `httr` does not have
the correct default config.

What does the following return?

`library(httr)
with_verbose(GET("http://httpbin.org/get"))`

The result may help in determining the correct config for `httr`.

Note that in `httr` you can set the global config with `httr::set_config`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the code you suggested, but I have no clue what the output means. Do you know how I could change the set_config settings so that it works?